# position: relative; style destroying my select dropdown animation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-material-design

Class `col-md-6` destroying my `ng-select` dropdown animation

When I disabled it from browser's developer tool everything looks fine.
When I replace styles of class `col-md-6` to this :

```
.col-md-6 {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

everything works, but i can't just replace `position: relative;` for all my layout, so i need the solution that help me remove that style only for my select.
i tried to overwrite class `col-md-6` to another twin class but it doesnt seem to work properly. Works **ONLY** when i edit original `col-md-6` class. Help me!
i adding few snippets to make it clearly.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-broken-select">
      //this select conflict with "Example paragraf" 
      <mdb-select [options]="colorSelect" placeholder="Choose your option" class="colorful-select dropdown-primary"></mdb-select>
      <label>Blue select</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Example paragraf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
//work!!
.col-md-6 {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
//NOT work!!
.my-broken-select {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
//NOT work!!
 .col-md-6.my-broken-select {
     position: static;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 1px;
     padding-right: 15px;
     padding-left: 15px;
 }
//NOT work!!
.my-broken-select {
    position: static!important;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

EDIT:

That may be important. Style from my twin class is assigned to my broken div but still doesn't work properly... but when I disable already disabled style from original `col-md-6` its start working.

doesn't work:

[image]

http://prntscr.com/h48fkj

work:

[image]

http://prntscr.com/h48f93

Comment: Can you try `!important` in the twin class of **col-md-6**

Comment: I tried but did not work

Comment: Can you post your try?

Comment: try add style tag <div class="" ..style="position:static">

Comment: I tried but did not work too. please look at my updated question

Comment: Try ` position: unset`

Comment: added to twin class didn't work, but added to original - work.

Comment: @WitoldTkaczyk : can you give a jsfiddle?

Comment: this will be hard because I use Angular, but I will try put all my html

Comment: This makes no sense - going by your "EDIT" screenshots you can clearly see it is working, *it is over-qualifying* the default `position: relative` styles of `.col-md-6`, that's why it's crossed-out. There is no way a simple selector like `.col-md-6` could over-qualify a selector with more specificity like `.col-md-6.my-broken-select` or one with a rule that uses an `important` declaration - or even a style rule declared `inline`. There's something else going on here, there seems to be no indication that this is a specificity issue. If you can set up an Fiddle as a MCVE that might prove useful.

Comment: examples in my question are all my code. here is my code in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xSpgWxtJ7uxO1kGF8iYZ?p=preview.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve As it stands your live example produces no code for us to work with, troubleshoot or debug.

Comment: because I use a paid module that generates `mdb-select` I can't put this to my snipped. when I delete styles position: relative - animation works in case `position: relative` is still there - it doesn't work. like in my question I don't know what I can add more. this select is very similar to this from angular material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out.
The problem was that sneaky "Example paragraph" which still have `position: relative;`. That's why when I disable this style from original class everything starts working fine

When I increase z-index that eliminates `position: relative` effects so the solution looks like this :

```
 .my-broken-select {
    z-index: 1500
}
```

that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of `!important` you can easily override your code it's all about organize your code, I mean if you define `.my-broken-select` after `.col-md-6` it should override it correctly, hope this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9pf0xrm/) solve your issue.

**Update**

If you are using **Bootstrap** just put your custome css link after **Bootstrap** css link, see below to understand:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCustomeStyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- yourContent -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to edit this without touching my minified .css file. I editing this in my app.component.scss file. look at my EDIT section. this style is overwritten although it didn't work

Comment: This is angular and I use specified css file only for my component. these styles are already overwritten, look at my EDIT section

Comment: add `!important` to `position: static` **but you have to use** `.col-md-6.my-broken-select` **not only** `.my-broken-select` check again and update me with the result

Comment: it's not in your question just check again because it should work